# How to load .7z file on action script 3?

Tags: actionscript, action

I don't know how to load (decompress) a .7z file (compress by 7-zip) with action script.

Can you give me a demo please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that simply... the SDK only exists for C/C++/C#/Java languages. By the way it's an open source project so you are free to port the SDK in actioncscript.